# NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.common.AccountPicker

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to run this code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE));
    startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
}
```

But it fails on the `startActivityForResult` line with this error, which is unclear to me as i have copied-pasted from Google's official [documentation](https://google-developers.appspot.com/drive/quickstart-android).

```
11-06 00:30:12.050: E/AndroidRuntime(28580): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.common.AccountPicker
11-06 00:30:12.050: E/AndroidRuntime(28580):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(GoogleAccountCredential.java:231)
```

These are the step I have taken:

(1) registered my app in `Google API console`

(2) used Google plugin to eclipse and downloaded `drive-api.jar`

(3) added google-play-services via SDK manager in eclipse, and added reference to this project.

.

**update**

I have  followed this [link](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html), but it didn't help

does this means the device requires android API 17 and above?

That's very new. Before that there was no integration with google drive